How can i solve this error when installing flair
when installing flair with pycharm on windows i get this error
im using conda on pycharm i already tried with venv and i got the same error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\fateh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u0mlt8t3\sentencepiece_a000aad54e31418080721464f45f1b0d\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
          subprocess.check_call([
        File "C:\Users\fateh\miniconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\fateh\miniconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\fateh\miniconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\fateh\miniconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.```


Have you tried installing the package outside of PyCharm yet? And have you checked for known bugs and issues with both PyCharm and the package in question? Sometimes IDE envs will make things needlessly difficult, and setting up a venv yourself can magically fix the issue

I solved this error by working on conda venv with downgraded pyhthon 3.10.
